# Puppet Custom Provider - Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am trying to write a custom provider.
At the moment, when running puppet I am getting the following errors

> Could not autoload puppet/provider/vault_auth/vault_auth: Function Load Error for function'vault_cert::vault_auth': wrong number of arguments (given 0, exptected1)
> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not autoload puppet/type/vault_auth: Could not autoload puppet/provider/vault_auth/vault_auth: Function Load Error for function 'vault_cert::vault_auth': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Is there a way to see what is being passed between the module and the provider/type?

I have tried debug, test, trace and apart from the stack I get nothing of value.
Within the module I can print up all of the values of the variables my code uses.
But I haven't been able to do the same for my provider to see if the values are being passed on.

is there a way to see what is/isn't being passed between the module and the provider?
I am unable to show the code as it is for a company and not for public release.

Comment: We need to see the provider code to assist further.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the code to assist further. The error you get should be self-explanatory: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, exptected1)`